# difference between multivariable calculus and vector calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to understand the difference between multivariate calculus and Vector calculus. If it's mentioned f(x,y) = xy, is it a multivariate or the x,y can be considered as vector and therefore, its a vector calculus and gradient will be calculated?

Quoting from the https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01528.pdf
"To make it clear we are doing vector calculus and not just multivariate calculus, let’s consider what we do with the partial derivatives"

Note: I went through this link also [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617756/what-is-the-difference-between-advanced-calculus-vector-calculus-multivariable)

and it says"Calc 3 = multivariable calculus = vector analysis. A semester mostly working on partial derivatives, surface integrals, stuff like that. Introduction of Stokes and Green's thereoms". If there is a function f(x,y), it's not necessary that x,y are vectors?so, this is multivariate calculus?

Comment: Multivariable - when domain of functions have more one dimension, vector - when range.

Comment: They are roughly interchangeable, but it probably varies by region. In my mind multivariable calculus extends calculus to its full capacity when the domain and range can have dimension $\ge 1$. Vector calculus applies *that* to vector fields. But vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ are just points in $\Bbb R^3$ with a fancy name, so until you need to worry about more general manifolds or infinite dimensional vector fields, I don't think it matters a ton.